# How to connect single GPIO pins?

Tags: gpio, connectors

I want to connect an IR receiver and a gas meter impluse reader to the GPIO port.

I saw those ribbon cables, but they have much more wires than needed.

Can I by these small connectors for single GPIO pins somewhere to connect them to my cables? For example with crimping?

[image: These plugs I am talking about]

Image source: http://www.partsdata.de/USB-Montagekabel_A_an_5x_Boardstecker_50cm_CU-VLMI-005.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what type of connectors your sensors have. If you have standard 0.1" headers, you can use `jumper wires`. Depending on the other end of connection (for RaspberryPi side you have to use Female connectors), you can use female to female (`F-F`) or female to male (`F-M`) `jumper wires`. They should be easy to buy on any hobbyst electronics shop. You need female side for connecting to RaspberryPi. They are very often used with `breadboards` which are very handy for prototyping

If, on the other hand, you don't have any connectors on your sensors and you are going to solder them, you can cut F-F jumper wires in half and just one one end for RaspberryPi.

It is also possible to make your own headers but you need `Crimper Pliers` and `Crimp pins` with housing. This is much more expensive to get.